# MS SQL: Pivot / transpose table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in my MS SQL server:

```
User | Item | Date
1    | A    | 2015-03-01
1    | B    | 2015-03-03
1    | C    | 2015-03-02
1    | A    | 2015-03-05
2    | C    | 2015-03-01
2    | C    | 2015-03-03
2    | B    | 2015-03-02
```

And this table should be aggregated / pivoted / transposed into this:

```
User | 1st_item | 2nd_item | 3rd_item | 4th_item
1    | A        | C        | B        | A
2    | C        | B        | C        | NULL
```

(The order of the items is defined by the date in the original data.)
Unfortunately I have no clue how to get there...
Ideally the solution would also work for a flexible number of items (not fixed to 4 as in the example).

What I tried so far:

- I used ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date) to generate a column giving me the order within each user's items
- I tried using PIVOT - but here I have no clue how to get the items into the columns added by this command

Thanks for any help and/or hint in advance!

Comment: can there be more than 4 items per user?

Comment: There might be more then 4. But for now it would be OK to limit it to 4...

Comment: Well, you can try doing it with the `ROW_NUMBER()` like you suggested and combine it with conditional aggregation : 

    `SELECT t.user, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 1 THEN t.item END) as 1st_item,
           MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 2 THEN t.item END) as 2nd_item,
           MAX(CASE WHEN t.rnk = 3 THEN t.item END) as 3rd_item
    FROM (SELECT s.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.user ORDER BY s.date) as rnk
          FROM YourTable s)
    GROUP BY t.user`

Comment: sage - thank you! This does the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot example

```
SELECT  [User],
        [1] AS [1st_item],
        [2] AS [2nd_item],
        [3] AS [3rd_item],
        [4] AS [4th_item]
FROM    (SELECT [User],
                [Item],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Date]) Rn
        FROM    myTable) mt
PIVOT (
    MAX([Item])
    FOR Rn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) p
```

Comment: Thank you - also this does solve my problem! When I tried it, I used AVG or SUM instead of MAX which then did not work out with a item string...